# Setting an image on a JLabel by opening the image from a Opendialog box

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I am trying to set an image of JPG format over a JLabel, taken by browsing through the files of the system. Below is given the code. On running this code I am getting a very small white icon in place of my large label placed over the form.
How can I place the original image over the label.Please help me through this.
I am using java language on NetBeans 7.0.

```
//Code of the browse button that performs the action
private void BrowseButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
       final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
      int r = fc.showOpenDialog(CompareFaces.this);

      fc.setFileSelectionMode(fc.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

      if (r == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      String name = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
      BrowseField1.setText(name);

      File f = new File(name);
      Icon icon = fc.getIcon(f);
      Preview1.setIcon(icon);  // Preview1 is the name of my JLabel 
      }
```

Comment: @heisenbug - I tried this too but no result, even the little white icon has also stopped replacing the label. Nothing is happening now, only just the field is showing the opened file's path.

Comment: my previous answer was wrong, sorry. I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to display the image in its original format then try this, it worked for me:

```
Preview1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(name));
```

Instead of:

```
File f = new File(name);
Icon icon = fc.getIcon(f);
Preview1.setIcon(icon);  // Preview1 is the name of my JLabel
```

JFileChooser.getIcon documentation says:

> Returns the icon for this file or type of file, depending on the
>   system.

This means that the code you posted will display the image type icon
as defined in your OS configuration not the image itself.